# How do I add a text file in the same location as the results of Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm searching a directory recursively for files that match a certain pattern and when I get a match I want to create a text file in that specific directory.

My directory structure looks like:

```
\fldr1\1\
\fldr1\2\
\fldr1\3\
```

My current code (powershell v5.1)

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*13000__CLMR*.PDF" -Recurse | foreach {New-Item -Path $_.Parent.FullName -ItemType File -Force -Name "DELETEME.txt"}
```

Returns the following error:
`New-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.`

Comment: Try `$_.Directory.FullName` instead of `$_.Parent.FullName`.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Can you add it as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: It's ok. ... 'glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Olaf for the answer. It was to use

```
$_.Directory.FullName
```

instead of

```
$_.Parent.FullName
```